# SEM brushed DC servo has stuck brake & disassembly help

Tags: motor, dc, servo

29 in/lb servo dynamics brushed DC servo motor, brake will not release when power is applied.  Motor data plate indicates 24vdc 44in/lb holding capability.  Brake terminals at the motor measure 74 Ohms and an ammeter in series reads 0.346A when 24vdc is applied.  I can override the spindle brake (without voltage applied) with torque of 39 in/lbs and that does not decrease at all with power applied and is smooth and consistent so I don't think I've dropped a magnet and it is not jammed.  This is an older servo but was working prior to being put into storage, I'm doing a CNC control retrofit.  There is almost no info on the net about disassembly of brushed DC servos other than (possibly overstated by repair facilities?) that its not possible other than by a qualified shop because of demagetization, etc.  I would just like to take the end bell off to access the brake and make sure it is not just packed with carbon dust, brake dust or delaminated/swollen brake pad material. The encoder would need to come off (easy) and there is a 7v/1000 rpm tach just under the end cover, then probably the brake, which I can't see but may be at either end of the armature. I have a complete machine shop here and have taken apart and repaired many induction and universal motors but need more information to proceed.  This motor was used vertically with pulley end down. any tips?

Comment: How about a couple of paragraph breaks (2 x <Enter>) to break up the wall of text? Please make sure that you capitalise brand names, etc., to make them clear and 'V' for volt. Hit the [edit] link.

Comment: The brake may be polarized - did you try it wired opposite?

Comment: When you have to shoot, shoot ...don't talk. Take it apart, it's just a motor..

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark the end bell and frame before removing the end bell to make sure it is aligned the same way when reassembling.

If this is a permanent-magnet motor, the rotor will be drawn to collide with the stator magnets as soon as it can move once the end bell is no longer holding the bearing in place. You need to work out a way to keep that from being a hard collision.

If you are going to remove the rotor, the brushes need to be moved away from the commutator. You may need to insert some kind of spacer material in the air gap so the rotor won't be held against the stator magnets.

Comment: I just got some information that indicates the brake is behind the front flange, which reinforces the theory that debris may have accumulated at that end because thats the way it has been oriented.  My goal then is to leave the rotor in place while removing the front end flange from the brake and shaft/bearing assy so I can vacuum then blow off any accumulated debris that may be preventing the brake from retracting.  not quite sure how I can hold the rotor centered in place while pulling the front flange, but I'm hoping I can get it out enough to at least see if there is stuff in there somehow

Comment: I thought about trying reverse voltage to the brake but the wires are color coded black and red and I'm afraid I'll ruin the coil if I do that?

Comment: As soon as the front flange is disengaged from the housing, the rotor is going to be be pulled to the stator. You will need to either be able to keep it from hitting too hard or have some means to block it from moving. By "front" do you mean drive end or non driver end?

Comment: by front I mean output shaft end.  I find it hard to believe that the brake is on that end but someone from the manufacturer said that was the case.  I should be able to confirm that when I take off the plate on the opposite end to remove the tachometer brush holder (probably monday)

Comment: In that case, you could conceivably clamp the end of the shaft and slide the end bell to the clamp. That would give you some access to the components in that end of the motor. Have you searched for general information about removing the rotor of a permanent-magnet motor?

Comment: I will be making a fixture to hold the armature shaft centered while pulling the front flange forward on the shaft if I need to go that far.  Going to be some work as I will need to make front and rear clamps for the motor body and one to support the shaft (up and down and sided to side) too.

Comment: It appears that sometimes a Nomex paper material is inserted between the rotor and stator when removing the rotor. However it is probably best not to remove the rotor. If you keep the motor vertical, you can probably remove the upper end bell completely. If the lower bearing and end bell are securely in place, the rotor should stay centered.

Comment: I'm hoping that is the case, but without a fixture to hold the shaft centered I think the rotor might move enough to contact the stator. I don't want to remove it but I'm hoping if I take the tachometer plate off I can see how much clearance there is and either do the nomex thing or insert some phenolic or plastic laminate strips. I've done a bunch of searching and have found very little info on how this is done as a normal practice at motor shops.  Lots of video on ac servos nothing on brushed DC ones

Comment: OK so after much thought I clamped the rear of the motor body in a lathe 3 jaw chuck as it was only 4" OD, chucked a dead center smaller than the motor shaft in the tailstock and moved it up to hold the motor shaft centered.  I then was able to easily slide off the motor front flange but had to remove the front bearing from the armature.

Comment: ... to access the brake.  To do this I took a small bearing separator and put a small section of rod in where the clamp bolts usually are (so it would fit) and tucked it behind the bearing, then a SECOND, larger bearing separator on the end of the shaft between the shaft and the dead center.  I was able to run bolts thru the large one into the small one and pull the bearing.  Everything was then slid up the thin dead center to allow access to the brake.  I was able to clean that, verify operation and use the bolts in the front flange to reseat the front bearing.  All is well now.